# Squid proxy - Find urls that are consuming the most bandwidth

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, ubuntu-14.04

I have squid proxy setup on my home network (squid is running on Ubuntu server, 14.04). Right now our home internet usage is about 2TB per month. I would like to find out which sites/urls/domains are consuming the most bandwidth.

Where do I need to look in Squid to find that out? I would prefer a solution that doesn't require installing PHP, Apache, database, or any extra software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of squid analyzers but unfortunately some of them seem to be out of date. http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/log-analysis.html

In the past I used [LightSquid](http://lightsquid.sourceforge.net/) but it requires Apache.

I tested with [Calamaris](http://cord.de/calamaris-english) and found that this old perl script worked perfect.

```
mkdir logfile
cd logfile/
wget http://cord.de/files/calamaris/calamaris-2.59.tar.gz
tar xvfz calamaris-2.59.tar.gz
cd calamaris-2.59/
cat /var/log/squid3/access.log | ./calamaris -a
```

use -h for list with more options

```
cat /var/log/squid3/access.log | ./calamaris -h
```

Comment: calamaris did it for me. I used the following command: sudo cat /var/log/squid3/access.log | calamaris -d 100 -O